# How to fix this Proguard issue?

Tags: android, proguard

- I have removed proguard from my app but still I am facing this
  exception from proguard.
- I am using Crashlytics and released four versions of my app after
  removing proguard but I am getting this exception in large numbers
  everyday in last released version only since last few days.
- I just can't understand that why it is coming this many times in last
  version rather in older versions it was coming 2 or 3 times.

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
>          at com.x.c.l.d(ProGuard:713)
>          at com.x.c.e.c(ProGuard:161)
>          at com.x.b.a.a(ProGuard:41)
>          at com.x.b.a$1.run(ProGuard:646)
>          at com.x.c.o$1.run(ProGuard:110)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

I am using eclipse and here is my project.properties file.

```
#This project.properties file is being managed by Fabric.
#Manifest merger has been enabled to pull in kit resources.
#Fri Jun 10 14:46:12 IST 2016
manifestmerger.enabled=true
android.library.reference.3=..\\ScratchViewLibrary
target=android-19
android.library.reference.2=..\\simple-crop-image-lib
android.library.reference.1=..\\facebook
android.library.reference.4=..\\kit-libs\\io-fabric-sdk-android_fabric
android.library.reference.5=..\\kit-libs\\com-crashlytics-sdk-android_crashlytics-core
android.library.reference.6=..\\kit-libs\\com-crashlytics-sdk-android_crashlytics
android.library.reference.7=../google-play-services_lib
```

Why this issue is coming? and How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This issue is nothing related to code level or proguard setting in apps. Many apps are facing this:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220567

Answer (score 0):

Use proguard-rules.pro and add this

```
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-printmapping mapping.txt
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep class !android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.**,android.support.** {*;}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but I have removed proguard so these rules doesn't matter.

Comment: I am using eclipse and now I have added my project.properties file. please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `minifyEnabled false` in your `gradle` file, or remove you can also remove this statement if you are not using `proguard`

```
 minifyEnabled false
 proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Comment: I am using eclipse and now I have added my project.properties file. please take a look.